# Behavior in BackgroundService with very long processes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, task, background-service

I start to deal with BackgroundServices in ASP Net Core(C#). I tested something in the method (ExecuteAsync) for this and put each new job (`String link`) in a queue and the processing works.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
  String link;

  while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
    if (Queue.TryDequeue(out link)) {
      await longProcess(link);

    }

    await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
  }

}
```

But what happens if the process (in longProcess(String link)) takes a long time and in the meantime there is a new entry in the queue ?

Comment: The obvious answer to your question is that each entry in the queue will have to wait until the previous entry has been processed. Maybe you wanted to ask something different?

Comment: Hello @TheodorZoulias and thank you for your reply:
wanted to know what happens when the process is still working while a new "order" comes in from the outside, I'm not sure if waiting is done.

Comment: By nature of the word `await`, it will.. wait.. until `longProcess` is finished before moving on to the next statement - `Delay(2000)`, then back to the `while` loop. So other processes can add to the Queue, but this process will only process them one at a time, with 2s delays in between each.